# How to drag down conditional formatting similarly to how you drag formulas in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

What I want to achieve is: If End Date is less than Start Date, then the End Date cell will be highlighted as red. But I do not know how to achieve this. Below is an image of the conditional formatting rules manager containing the formula and cell to be formatted. But I want this condition to be true until the last cell and I wouldn't want to create a rule for each row.

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Applies To: to a full column reference ($H:$H) and the formula to,

```
 =and(row($h1)>1, $h1<$g1)
```